# Values in CGRectMake

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a cropped image of the captured image. I used tap gesture to find the points so that I can crop the image accordingly.

```
func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println(sender.locationInView(self.view).x)
    println(sender.locationInView(self.view).y)
    //self.xLabel.text = "x: \(xPoint)"
    //self.yLabel.text = "y: \(yPoint)"
}
```

Then I used CGRectMake to create a rectangle with these points.

```
 func displayPhoto() {

        let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        var ID = imageManager.requestImageForAsset(photoAsset[self.index] as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result: UIImage!, info: [NSObject: AnyObject]!)in
            //self.imgView.image = result
            //self.imageSpectrum = result
            var imageGot:UIImage = result
            var croprect:CGRect = CGRectMake(3.0, 239.5, 237.5, 22.0)
            var imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageGot.CGImage, croprect)
            var croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: imageGot.scale, orientation: imageGot.imageOrientation)!
            self.imgView.image = croppedImage
            self.imageSpectrum = croppedImage

        })

    }
```

But it seems my values for CGRectMake are not correct. I think I need to give pixel values.
But I am not sure what's the difference between pixel values and the values I am giving.
Could you guys help me with understanding this concept of points. 
Which type of points should I use in CGRect???

Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you read [the `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect ` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect) yet? It's very clear about how it uses the rect you pass in.

Comment: If that doesn't help, please update your question to be more specific - what behavior are you expecting? What is happening instead? Can you link to sample images  to show us what's wrong? All you've said is that it's "not correct" which isn't much to go on.

Comment: I am just confused regarding the coordinates to choose. It seems we have two types of coordinate system. 
One uses pixels as points in which case we have 3264 on x-axis and 2448 on y-axis.
Second uses geometry coordinates in which we have 320 on x-axis and 570 on y-axis.
Which coordinates to use when?